# How to determine http status code in range error handler

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

What I'd like to do is:

```
error 400..510 do
    {:'400' => 'Bad Request', :'401' => ...}[<http-status-code>.to_s.to_sym]
end
```

where `<http-status-code>` is some expression, evaluated to error code to be returned. One possible way the handler is triggered:

```
get '/test' do
    401
end
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: If you want achieve different behaviours, why you don't simply catch each status code with `error 400 do`, `error 401 do` ... ?

Comment: That's what I did. But I hoped it could be done with less code...

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Net::HTTP request. The output of that request will be a Net::HTTPResponse object. For example, from the Ruby Net::HTTP documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
res.code
```

Comment: You must be getting me wrong. I'm trying to determine status code of _current request_. And if you're suggesting to make subrequest to determine status code, that would be overkill. (I've slightly updated the question.)